# Surface Mount Ceiling Fan with Conduit to a Half Hot plug

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I'd like to put a ceiling fan in a room and connect it to a half-hot outlet.  I don't have access to the crawlspace above so I'll need to use a surface mount box to hang the fan.  What's the safe way to connect it to the outlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is *precisely* what surface raceway is for

What you want to do is use surface raceway to bring the switched hot, neutral, and ground from the half-hot outlet to the new fan location.  You'll need to put a compatible extension box (starter box) on the outlet to provide room for the connections, and use a raceway system (Legrand's B-series metal raceways work) that has a fan-rated box (B4F/BW4F in the Legrand B-series) available.  As to wiring inside the raceway, you can run a NM cable or single THHN wires.

(As a sidenote, EMT with standard boxes and fittings also works for running exposed wiring safely, but you may have trouble finding a surface mountable fan-rated box outside of a surface raceway system.)

Comment: What does EMT stand for in this context?

Comment: Figured it out - Electrical Metallic Tubing.